# How can I install my Eclipse plug-in from the Eclipse Marketplace?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, equinox, p2

We've set up an update site for our plug-in called [CodingSpectator](http://codingspectator.cs.illinois.edu/) and we've added it to Eclipse Marketplace to make it even easier to install our plug-in (See http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/codingspectator/). But, we are unable to find CodingSpectator in the listings at `Help -> Eclipse Marketplace...` on Eclipse Helios SR2.

Why isn't it possible to find CodingSpectator at `Help -> Eclipse Marketplace...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The search in the marketplace client is not the best - it does not always find plug-ins on their full name. However, when writing Coding as a search term, I could select the result as the first one provided in the "Further result" option.

**Update**: in 2011, when writing this post, I had some issues finding our plug-ins in the Marketplace, even with precisely writing their names. Today (10th Oct, 2016), I could not reproduce the exact behaviour. I don't know whether the issue was fixed by updating the search, or the indexes require some time to be updated with new(ish) plug-ins.

Comment: I searched for "Coding" in the dialog at `Help -> Eclipse Marketplace...` and clicked on the link "Browse for more solutions" at the end of the search results page. This link opened the web page http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/apachesolr_search/Coding?mpc=true&mpc_state= in Eclipse. Then, I clicked on the "Install" button of CodingSpectator on the web page to install CodingSpectator on my Eclipse. It is a pity that the search in the Marketplace client doesn't work well.

Comment: What exactly the problem is with the search feature of the Markplace Eclipse client? I thought it might have something to do with the two capital letters in the name of our solution ("CodingSpectator"). But, renaming the solution to "codingspectator" didn't help.

Comment: Sadly, I do not know. I have seen similar issues with the Debug Visualisation plug-in. When writing the full name, it mostly does not work, but writing a part of the name usually helps.

Comment: "The search in the marketplace client is not the best" - do you have verifiable sources for that claim? Is this documented? Has anyone filed a bug report already?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the old issues anymore. I don't know what has caused it in the past.

Answer (score 3):

If I get `0` matches, I click on `"Browse for more solutions."`. And there I found your `CodingSpectator`. And I can insall it.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from the Marketplace Client Content Inclusion Policy [1](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/marketplace-client-content-inclusion-policy):

> Solutions listed in the MPC Wizard will only be those that are 1) licensed under an open source license or 2) associated with an Eclipse Foundation member company (excluding Associate Members).

So if your plugin is open source, you can set the license type to the appropriate open-source license.